# Adjective relating to Great Britain and Ireland

Tags: adjectives, geography, hiberno-english, insular-english, demonyms

Is there an adjective meaning “from or pertaining to the British Isles” (or if you prefer “from Great Britain, Ireland or surrounding islands”, or “from the Atlantic Archipelago”, or [whatever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Isles_naming_dispute#Names_of_the_islands_through_the_ages) floats your boat)? I'm obviously not looking for *British*, but for a term that could be acceptable to an Irish person. I'm primarily looking for an adjective applicable to concepts relating to this geographical region, but if there's a demonym, that would be interesting too.

In other words, if Webster's is English beer, Tennent's is Scottish beer, both are British beer, and Guinness is Irish beer, what adjective can apply to all three?

Comment: If there was a suitable term that didn't upset the Irish, I don't suppose there'd be a Wikipedia page on the [British Isles naming dispute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Isles_naming_dispute#Names_of_the_islands_through_the_ages). But apart from the Irish themselves, no-one (including the English) really distinguishes much between, say, British and English, or worries about whether The British Isles includes Ireland or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What are The British Isles? Surely you meant the British Isles.

Comment: @tchrist: Nah. Lots of isles and islands are "British *ordinaire*" (the Falklands, for example). But Ireland is privileged to be part of ***The** British* ones! :)

Comment: What's the adjective for Germany and Poland.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane There is none, but that's unsurprising given that “Germany and Poland” is an arbitrary union of two geographical areas that do not form a geologically or politically relevant set, unlike the British Isles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the [British and Irish Lions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_Irish_Lions) suggests that, in practice, the term you seek is "British and Irish".

Comment: You know, I almost find the idea of there being ‘Britirish Islanders’ perversely appealing. :)